# domain users logon info

Tags: wmi

i want to know how to find list of domain users whcih entered at my PC (some local groups included domain groups and domain users can enter at my PC).

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but you might find it helpful to know that logins are recorded in the windows security event log with event id 528.